# Adding of ellipsis and combobox to a datagridview column in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a datagridview having 1 rows and 1 columns.

I want to add one ellipsis to one cell and to add combobox to another cell of same column.

Also I have some events to be fired on click of ellipsis.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Swarna